# can't download android sdk on fresh installation of android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2

Tags: android, android-studio

I can not download new sdk! My latest sdk is Android version 11!

[image]
This is a problem. I tried every proxy and VPN but still could not download the new sdk. Where is the problem?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the "SDK Update Sites", please?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Open your SDK update sites and see if you're missing any.Then add as needed

Comment: There is a plus symbol at the top. Use that to include as necessary